# How to merge columns with no header name in a python script?

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

My Python script parsed some text of a Excel file. It strips white-space from an Excel file and changes the delimiters
(from " : "-->  " , ")

and my script outputs to a CSV file. Much of the data looks like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMz19.png)
(what data looks like in Excel)

Separated by a single column due to there being a extra comma or two.

CSV == Comma separated values.

I have tried using if statements to add or subtract commas to try shore it up but it ends up completely messing up the relative order it was first in. Driving me nuts!

To try do it another way installed the pandas library (a data manipulating library) using pip.

Is it possible to merge columns that have *no* column headers inside a single Data Frame? There's plenty of advice regarding separate DataFrames but much for one single one.

Furthermore how can I merge the columns while retaining the row position. The emails are in the correct row position but not the column position.

Or am I on the wrong track completely, is pandas overkill for a simple parsing script? I've been learning python as I go along to try complete the script so I might have missed a simple way of doing it.

Some sample data:

> ```
> C5XXEmployeeNumXX,C5XXEmployeeNumXX,JohnSmith,1,,John,,Smith,,IT Supp.Centre,EU,,London1,,,59XXXX,ITServiceDesk,LOND01,,,,Notmaintained,,,,,,,,john.smith@company.com,
> ```

Snippet of parsing logic

```
    for line in f:
    
    #finds the identifier for users
    if ':LON ' in line:
        
        #parsing logic.
        #Delimiters are swapped. Whitespace is scrubbed
        line = line.replace(':', ',')
        line = line.replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Comment: @IanS Of course. I will post it in the question.

Comment: Can you also show your code and explain exactly why you're unhappy with what it does?

Comment: @IanS  The issue is there are many rows some of which are missing entries. When the white-space is scrubbed portions of the entries are not in a single column. Another team want to use the output of my script for an API and need to have it in order. 

Nearly all of the data is separated by a single empty column and when I tried alter the amount of commas it becomes far too unmanageable and far spread apart. I am looking on advice or suggestions on what to do to try and merge separated values under a single column.

Comment: @IanS I hope that clarified things a little bit. :)

Comment: Can you add several rows of the raw text input? And then your desired result from those rows? It's too abstract at the moment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user a separator/delimiter of your choice. Check out: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter.

Also, regarding the order, if you are reading in a list it should be fine but if you are reading the contents of a row in a dict then it is normal that the order is not preserved.